# Find the Cardinality of the set $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S$ = {${T: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}}$ such that $T$ is a linear transformation over field $ \mathbb{R}$ with $T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3)$ and $T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)$ , find $|S|$ .

**Attempted:**

As a L.T. is uniquely determined when it is defined on a basis of it's domain space .But here {$(1,0,1)$ , $(1,2,3) $} is not a basis , therefore $T$ will not be unique $ \implies S \not=\phi$ , is not a singleton set.

Now let { $(1,0,1),(1,2,3),(x,y,z)$ } ;let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$  be a basis. So $(x,y,z)$ is not a linear combination of the rest two. Hence $T$ is not *fixed* and we can take any output for $T(x,y,z)$ ,say $(a,b,c)$ but field is $\mathbb{R}$ ,so $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable ,so is $S$.

**Questions:**

(1) Whether my concept is correct or wrong?

(2) Will the cardinality of $S$ always be depending on the field?

Comment: It has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is $\cal c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concept is correct.  I would express it a bit differently.  Instead of $(x,y,z)$ I would pick an explicit vector that makes a basis with the other two, say $(1,0,0)$.  Then, as you say, you can send $(1,0,0)$ anywhere so the cardinality of $T$ is the same as the target space, which here is $\mathfrak c$.  For $2$, it clearly depends on the base field.  If your space were $\Bbb Q^3$ it is only countably infinite, so the cardinality of $T$ is also.  If your space were over a finite field, it would be finite....